# Finding Competitor Prices for the latest Updated Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the latest competitor prices for the Items from the table that has different last_checked dates (timestamps).

I am trying to find the price for OKJ seller and the lowest price for that item for the latest updated last_checked date.

- Isbb denotes the lowest price
- if amxcd is the seller for an item in the latest timestamp update then I should not select that item , Also if isfba =1 for an item for the latest timestamp date then I should not select that item
- I also need to count the number of sellers for the items that I am selecting
- if okj is a competitor in the latest timestamp date then I need to say 'yes' else 'no'

--Input table

```
create table #input
(itemid varchar(50),
seller varchar(30),
price int,
last_checked datetime2,
is_bb int,
isfba int
)

insert into #input 
values
('bclpa','amxcd','89','2019-07-17 14:04:00.000','1','1'),
('bclpa','cvbd','100','2019-07-17 14:04:00.000','0','0'),
('lpatt','cvbd','78','2019-04-17 14:04:00.000','0','0'),
('lpatt','bnhj','60','2019-04-17 14:04:00.000','1','0'),
('lpatt','okj','90','2019-04-17 14:04:00.000','0','0'),
('lpatt','cvbd','70','2018-04-17 14:04:00.000','1','0'),
('lpatt','hjnk','90','2018-04-17 14:04:00.000','0','1'),
('cjatt','klmn','45','2019-04-17 14:04:00.000','1','0'),
('cjatt','njkl','89','2019-04-17 14:04:00.000','0','1'),
('cjatt','lket','40','2018-04-17 14:04:00.000','1','0'),
('cjatt','jklop','76','2018-04-17 14:04:00.000','0','0'),
('tilo','okj','56','2019-02-17 14:04:00.000','1','0'),
('tilo','jklop','70','2019-02-17 14:04:00.000','0','0'),
('tilo','hjkl','88','2019-02-17 14:04:00.000','0','0'),
('tilo','amxcd','32','2018-02-17 14:04:00.000','1','0'),
('jkatt','jklop','22','2018-02-17 14:04:00.000','1','0'),
('jkatt','amxcd','56','2018-02-17 14:04:00.000','0','0'),
('katt','hjkl','90','2019-02-17 14:04:00.000','1','0'),
('katt','lklo','99','2019-02-17 14:04:00.000','0','0'),
('katt','bnm','108','2019-02-17 14:04:00.000','0','0'),
('katt','okj','78','2018-02-17 14:04:00.000','1','0'),
('katt','nmsd','80','2018-02-17 14:04:00.000','0','0')
```

----Ouptut table

```
create table #output
( itemid varchar(50),
okjprice int,
lowestprice int,
noofcompetitors int,
isokjacompetetior varchar(20)
)

insert into #output values
('lpatt','90','60','3','Yes'),
('tilo','56','56','3','yes'),
('katt','','90','3','No')
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  : I am using SQL server management studio 2018

Comment: Can you post your query you tried so far?

Comment: @mkrabbani: its

Comment: with cte
as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by itemid order by last_checked desc) rn from #input 
) select * from cte where rn=1
 and seller not in  (select seller  from #input where seller ='amxcd' ) 
 and isfba <>1
 and is_bb=1

Comment: both last last_checked value is same for itemid = bclpa. Is that ok with you if any of the comes first with Row Number Order BY?

Comment: seems your data is wrong, there's no okj for lpatt: select * from input where itemid in ('lpatt') and isfba != 1 and is_bb=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this implements the logic you describe.  However, it includes two additional items:

```
select itemid,
       min(case when seller = 'okj' then price end) as okj_price,
       min(price) as min_price,
       sum(is_bb) as num_competitors,
       max(case when is_bb = 1 and seller = 'okj' then 'yes' else 'no' end) as isokjcompetitor
from (select i.*,
             first_value(seller) over (partition by itemid order by last_checked desc) as last_seller,
             first_value(isfba) over (partition by itemid order by last_checked desc) as last_isfba
      from input i
     ) i
where last_isfba <> 1 and last_seller <> 'amxcd'
group by itemid;
```

Based on your description, "cjatt" and "kjatt" should be in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this query:

```
;WITH    CTE
          AS ( SELECT   A.itemid ,A.seller ,A.price ,A.last_checked ,A.is_bb ,A.isfba ,
                        CASE WHEN A.seller = 'okj' THEN A.price ELSE 0 END AS okjPrice ,
                        DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY A.itemid ORDER BY A.last_checked DESC ) GrpID ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY A.itemid ORDER BY A.last_checked DESC, A.is_bb DESC, A.price ASC ) RowID
               FROM     #input A
             )
    SELECT  A.itemid , OP.okjPrice , A.price AS lowestprice , OP.Cnt AS noofcompetitors ,
            CASE WHEN OP.okjPrice > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS isokjacompetetior
    FROM    CTE A
            INNER JOIN ( SELECT CTE.itemid , MAX(CTE.okjPrice) okjPrice ,
                                COUNT(*) AS Cnt
                         FROM   CTE
                         WHERE  CTE.GrpID = 1
                         GROUP BY CTE.itemid
                       ) OP ON OP.itemid = A.itemid
    WHERE   A.RowID = 1
            AND A.isfba <> 1;
```

The output for the query is:

```
itemid  okjPrice    lowestprice noofcompetitors isokjacompetetior
cjatt       0           45          2               No
jkatt       0           22          2               No
katt        0           90          3               No
lpatt       90          60          3               Yes
tilo        56          56          3               Yes
```